# How to format date_add

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this column 'formatteddate' and it is varchar

now I want to get last 2 days
  `WHERE formatteddate > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY)`

how to format this part `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY)` to looks like this example `20180731` so that I can compare it to my formattedate.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use str_to_date for  foramt your string as  a date and the compare the two dates

```
 WHERE str_to_date(formatteddate,'%Y%m%d') > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -12, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Server Collation default

Comment: That's not what the OP asked for